# Would it be possible to change the select option value when selecting corresponding select option with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I would like to know if it would be possible to change the select option value when selecting another select option - I know it sounds odd, but please see the code below:

When I select the option "Ball" from the "item" options, then the "img" and "item" options change to "ball.png" and "ball.gif". And visa versa?

```
    <label for="item">Item:</lable>
    <select name="item">
        <option value="Ball">Ball</option>
        <option value="Door">Door</option>
        <option value="Pen">Pen</option>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    </select>

    <label for="img">Image:</lable>
    <select name="img">
        <option value="ball.png"><img src="ball.png"></option>
        <option value="door.png"><img src="door.png"</option>
        <option value="pen.png"><img src="pen.png"</option>
        <option value="apple.png"><img src="apple.png"</option>
    </select>

    <label for="item">Image Animation:</lable>
    <select name="item">
        <option value="ball.gif"><img src="ball.gif"</option>
        <option value="door.gif"><img src="door.gif"</option>
        <option value="pen.gif"><img src="pen.gif"</option>
        <option value="apple.gif"><img src="apple.gif"</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Your 3rd select has the same name as the 1st.  Other than that, yes it's simple enough.  Have you tried anything, like a jQuery `on("change")` handler?

Comment: add in your onchange $("[name='img']").val("ball.png");

Comment: Close the img tags with `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work

```
<label for="item">Item:</lable>
<select name="item" id="select-1">
    <option value="Ball">Ball</option>
    <option value="Door">Door</option>
    <option value="Pen">Pen</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
</select>

<label for="img">Image:</lable>
<select name="img" id="select-2">
    <option value="ball.png"><img src="ball.png"></option>
    <option value="door.png"><img src="door.png"></option>
    <option value="pen.png"><img src="pen.png"></option>
    <option value="apple.png"><img src="apple.png"></option>
</select>

<label for="item">Image Animation:</lable>
<select name="animation" id="select-2">
    <option value="ball.gif"><img src="ball.gif"></option>
    <option value="door.gif"><img src="door.gif"></option>
    <option value="pen.gif"><img src="pen.gif"></option>
    <option value="apple.gif"><img src="apple.gif"></option>
</select>
<script>

   $("#select-1").on("change", function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#select-2").val(value.toLowerCase()+".png");
      $("#select-3").val(value.toLowerCase()+".gif");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: This is great!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but just being curious - what would happen if there are words with spaces? Are there possibly a "remove spaces" Jquery function? I did some google research but couldn't find something for that?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) link

Comment: Thanks @Bhavana. I wasn't aware of that function. Unfortunately, it only removes white space before and after a string, which lead me searching for a solution to remove 'inner space'. I got something from a Stackoverflow question which was  .replace(/\s/g, '');  I tried to implement it as value.replace(/\s/g, '');  and  $("#select-2").val(value.toLowerCase()+".png".replace(/ /g, ''));  but none worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it working!!! So the solution is:  $("#select-2").val(value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')+".png");   This removes the white space between the wording - e.g.   "hello world" would be "helloworld" :))